# Problems with gradle-svntools-plugin when performing an SvnUpdate task

Tags: gradle, svn

I am using the gradle-svntools-plugin to attempt to update my svn source etc. but am getting the following error when executing the task

> A problem occurred evaluating root project 'XBRLReports'.
>   Cannot cast object '12345' with class 'java.lang.String' to class 'java.lang.Long'

Here is the task in question :

```
task updateSource(type: SvnUpdate){
    username = svn_username
    password = svn_password

    if ( project.hasProperty("rev") ) {
        revision = rev
        println "Revision --- $rev"
    }
    doLast{
        println "Revision --- " + revision        
    }
}
```

The issue arises when I try and pass a command line variable like so

```
gradlew updateSource -Prev=12345
```

Manually setting **revision** to a static value also causes the issue.  Printing out the value of revision returns null.  I am not sure if this is a bug or if I am not properly using the plugin.  The documentation is vague for this task.  Here is the link to it --

[gradle-svntools-plugin SvnUpdate](https://github.com/martoe/gradle-svntools-plugin/blob/master/docs/SvnUpdate.md)

I have opened a ticket on github as well.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
if ( project.hasProperty("rev") ) {
    revision = rev.toLong()
    println "Revision --- $rev"
}
```

Comment: that did it!  Thanks.  I am fairly new to gradle so still learning these little tricks